# How to start a letter with self introduction to a friend you haven't seen for ages?

Tags: translation

I'd like to write a letter to a friend I haven't seen for ages. And it would be nice to remind who I am because I am not sure my name is just enough.

So I'd like to write the next sentence:

> This is your sports friend Xxxxx from [some country] writing to you.

Word order does not matter, the main purpose is clear chinese language to address to a friend.

Comment: sport friend?, friend in (outdoor?) sports, sports friend, 这是给你从XXX写信跟你一起做运动的一个朋友

Comment: @user6065, I mean we met because we were doing the same sport

Comment: "sports" may be a more common term, therefore sporting or sports friend may be more common,

Comment: What is the point of starting a letter with a Chinese sentence if you don't know Chinese? To impress your friend? of what? If I was that friend of yours, and knew you don't speak Chinese, I would expect you to write me in English.

Comment: If this sport is related to football, basketball, volleyball, golf, billiards, pingpong, tennis, badminton, or any other sports end with Chinese character 球, just simply put 我是你的xx (your nationality) 球友 yy (your name). More specifically if you play in pair for quite a long time, you could replace 球友 with 球搭子.

Comment: @TangHo, 就是我不喜欢用英语, 也许他的英语不太好

Answer (score 1):

你好，我是 Ivan Gerasimenko。
Hello, I am Ivan Gerasimenko.

我们之前在XXX的比赛第中见过一次面， 你还记得吗？
We met once before at the XXX sports competition, do you still remember?

距离上次见面已经很久了，你现在过得怎么样？
It's been a long time, how are you getting on these days?

(PS: Are you from Serbia? We just found out, Chinese people can go to Serbia without a visa.)

Comment: thank you! But you have missed one part " from [some country]". But it looks like you are going to suggest "你好，我是 Ivan Gerasimenko你的俄罗斯朋友。" 是吗?

Answer (score 0):

> Hi xxx,
>
> ```
>   你好！
>
>   还记得我吗，俄罗斯的球友-Ivan Gerasimenko？ ... ...
> ```

You can replace 球友 with other words if you guys were not playing a ball game.